# Custom module over ride blazy.html.twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I have a small custom module that needs override blazy.html.twig that comes from the Blazy contributed module in Drupal 8. The code below shows what I have so far, can anyone give me some direction on how to go about this?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */

function slider_overlay_text_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    // In the template file I have blazy.html.twig
    $templates = $path . '/templates';

    return [
            'template' => 'blazy',
            'path' => $templates
    ];
}


/**
 * Prepares variables for blazy.html.twig templates.
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for field templates.
 */
function slider_overlay_text_preprocess_blazy(&$variables) {

    // This variable is in the template ready to be printed
     $variables['display_hero_text'] = 'right-hero-text1';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue to override the module template you have to call the modules name in the _theme hook `$return['blazy']`.

```
function slider_overlay_text_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    $templates = $path . '/templates';

    $return['blazy'] = [
        'template' => 'blazy',
        'path' => $templates
    ];
    return $return;
}
```